# Assignment of Property Default Values in a Null Object Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this object `TrSet` that takes in nodes from the dom. Sometimes those dom elements can be null, and I want to handle properties of the nodes, unfortunately, I can't figure out how to use null conditional assignment on `undefined` properties.

```
var TrSet = function(valid,stat,txt,dd){
     this.validateField = valid || "";
     this.statusDropDown = stat || "";
     this.txtValue = txt || "";
     this.ddValue = dd || "";
     this.txtValue.value = txt.value || ""; //Cannot read property value of undefined
     this.ddValue.style.visibility = dd.style.visibility || "hidden"; //same

     this.validate = function () {
         /// Even when attempting to access 
         /// the property with hasOwnProperty throws the error 
         ///"Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null"!
       if (this.statusDropDown.hasOwnProperty("value") && this.validateField.hasOwnProperty("style")) {
```

I don't understand how either of these is failing. If it's null or undefined, it should evaluate to true for the empty string and set it equal to that.

**EDIT For Clarity**

> In the first example

```
var TrSet = function(txt) {
    this.txtValue = txt || "";
    this.txtValue.value = txt.value || "";
}
```

If `txt` is null set it equal to `""`, if `txt.value` is null set it equal to `""`. how does this fail?

Second example

```
var TrSet = function(stat) {
    this.statusDropDown = stat || "";

    if (this.statusDropDown.hasOwnProperty("value")) { }
```

If `stat` is null set `statusDropDown` equal to `""`. Then I check if if it `hasOwnProperty`. Why does this fail?

Comment: `this.statusDropDown.hasOwnProperty("value")` the `this` refers to the _function currently being executed_ - i.e., the one assigned to `this.validate` - you won't get the properties from outside.

Comment: After edit: same thing as my comment above. You aren't checking _that_ `statusDropDown`, you have an entirely new `this` which does not have a `statusDropDown` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand how either of these is failing. If it's null or undefined, it should evaluate to true for the empty string and set it equal to that.

Not quite: the statement `txt || ""` will *return* the value of `txt` or `""`, whichever is truthy first. It **does not** assign that value anywhere, especially not to `txt`. You assign separately.

Therefore, in your example (reduced to the necessary parts for example):

```
var TrSet = function(valid,stat,txt,dd){
  this.txtValue = txt || "";
  console.log('txt will still be undefined but txtValue will not be', txt, this.txtValue);
  this.txtValue.value = txt.value || "";
}
```

To do what you expect, you would need to default out `txt` again, like so:

```
var TrSet = function(valid,stat,txt,dd){
  this.txtValue = txt || "";
  console.log('txt will still be undefined but txtValue will not be', txt, this.txtValue);
  this.txtValue.value = (txt || "").value || ""; // <- change here
}
```

Of course, that's largely unreadable (how does `.value || ''` group? do you know at a glance?), so we'd probably cache it:

```
var TrSet = function(valid,stat,txt,dd){
  var realTxt = txt || ""
  this.txtValue = realTxt;
  this.txtValue.value = realTxt.value || "";
}
```

Now, that works, but is less than ideal. ES6 added the ability to provide a default directly in the parameter list, which is much cleaner:

```
var TrSet = function(valid = "", stat = "", txt = "", dd = "") {
  this.txtValue = txt;
  this.txtValue.value = txt.value || "";
}
```

To directly address the two brief questions you added:

> ```
> var TrSet = function(txt) {
>   this.txtValue = txt || "";
>   this.txtValue.value = txt.value || "";
> }
> ```
>
> If txt is null set it equal to "", if txt.value is null set it equal to "". how does this fail?

Because `txt || ""` **does not** *assign* to `txt`, it simply *returns* `txt` *or* `""` and that return value is assigned to `this.txtValue`.

> ```
> var TrSet = function(stat) {
>   this.statusDropDown = stat || "";
>
> if (this.statusDropDown.hasOwnProperty("value")) { }
> ```
>
> If stat is null set statusDropDown equal to "". Then I check if if it hasOwnProperty. Why does this fail?

Probably because `this` is not bound, so it doesn't actually have a value for `statusDropDown`. In JavaScript, `this` can change depending on how a function is called. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) for more details.

Comment: That makes sense. `this.txtValue.value = this.txtValue.value || ""` also seemed to work. How about my second example then? I updated my question.

Comment: @christopherclark have you verified that the functions are being called the same way in your real code? In particular, try logging `this` to make sure it has the value you're expecting.

Comment: I found the issue, I was calling `new TrSet()` thinking that I'm still passing null values so they would evaluate to the `""` regardless. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
this.txtValue.value = txt.value || "";
```

`txt` is `null`, and the attempt to reference a property on a null object results in an error.  You need to change it to:

```
this.txtValue.value = txt ? (txt.value || "") : "";
```

Test the variable for null before attempting to dereference it.